# Wordpress window manager button styling

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-3

Created a custom window in wordpress looking like:

[image]

Now I need the buttons `INSERT` and `CANCEL` (see picture above) to be looking like everywhere else (see picture below) like `CANCEL` and `Add Link`

[image]

This code gave me the window but I couldn't find any options to change the buttons. There must be something, or it should be something!? Even tried to change the styles (some of the styles get added with javascript) inline styles with `!important` but no effect ...

```
( function($) {
    tinymce.create( 'tinymce.plugins.hd_fancybox_button', {
        init: function( editor, url )  {

            editor.addButton( 'hd_fancybox_button', {
                icon: 'icons dashicons-icon',
                tooltip: 'Fancybox',
                cmd: 'plugin_command',
                image : url + '/img/popup-icon.png'
            });

            editor.addCommand( 'plugin_command', function() {
                editor.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'Fancybox',
                    width: 500,
                    height: 300,
                    inline: 1,
                    id: 'hd-fancybox-button-insert-dialog',
                    body: [
                        {
                            type    : 'textbox',
                            name    : 'title',
                            label   : 'Title',
                            classes : 'selected_image_title',
                        }, {
                            type    : 'button',
                            name    : 'button',
                            label   : 'Image',
                            text    : 'Image',
                            classes : 'upload_image_button'
                        }
                    ],
                    buttons: [{
                        text: 'Insert',
                        id: 'hd-fancybox-button-insert',
                        onclick: function( e ) {
                            insertImg(editor);
                            closeBox();
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        id: 'hd-fancybox-button-cancel',
                        onclick: 'close'
                    }],
                });

                appendInsertDialog();

            });

        }

    });
```

---

Now a few hours later I found out that I can use a `style` property like

```
{
    text: 'Cancel',
    id: 'hd-fancybox-button-cancel',
    onclick: 'close',
    style: 'background-color:orange;border:lime 1px solid;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;'
}
```

Isn't it great that you have the opportunity to add stlyes like this? Off course you can just change the colors...

[image]

Comment: look for these id's in your css files `#hd-fancybox-button-insert,#hd-fancybox-button-cancel`

Comment: @madalinivascu that's right I could kind a use those IDs but the position of the button gets set via javascript. And the parent element is not `relative` or anything. So I believe it want work to position them correctly via CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using the `style` property which I found here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.ui.Button like:

```
{
    text: 'Cancel',
    id: 'hd-fancybox-button-cancel',
    onclick: 'close',
    style: 'background-color:white;border:none;'
}
```

and at the end of the `appendInsertDialog();` function i added

```
    $('#hd-fancybox-button-cancel').css({
        'position'  : 'absolute',
        'left'      : '20px'
    }).children('button').css({
        'color'     : '#a00'
    });

    $('#hd-fancybox-button-insert').css({
        'position'  : 'absolute',
        'left'      : 'auto',
        'right'     : '20px',
    });
```

So it's the worst code solution you can probably find but the result looks almost like desired: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the buttons you want and add the classes to your button definition:

Example:

```
{
  text: 'Insert',
  id: 'hd-fancybox-button-insert',
  classes: 'button button-primary',
  onclick: function( e ) {
    insertImg(editor);
    closeBox();
  },
}
```

I'd only add this to the insert button, as it is the primary button of the dialog.

Comment: Thank you, but all that does is adding class names to the buttons. So problem is still the same

Comment: The classes define how the buttons look (and partly behave). If you want them to look like the WordPress buttons the easiest way is to use the corresponding classes. The alternative would be to recreate the style in your own stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for your time and that you are trying to help. I updated the question with some property I found somwhere in the world-wide-web ... so there is a property to trigger styles which I was looking for ... still a big pain to use it ...